# Evaluating $\int\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x-a_i)^{b_i}\mathrm dx$ using generalised Newton's binomial theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration, taylor-expansion, indefinite-integrals, binomial-theorem

This post is in reference to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3597589/int-x-a-1b-1-cdots-x-a-nb-n-dx) question which asks about the general antiderivative of the following function with the arbitrary constants $a_i,b_i\in \mathbb{R}\forall i\in[1,n]\cap\mathbb{Z^{+}}$.

$$\int\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x-a_i)^{b_1}\mathrm dx$$

It seems easy at first to generalise because this is practically a polynomial, but the source of ambiguity are the real exponents, because they seem to make applying the binomial theorem invalid.

I am thinking about using Taylor series for the $i$th term of the product, but again would we then center the series about the $a_i$? Also how to make sense of something like $(1+x)^{e}$? How to get a grip on it? Any hints are appreciated. Thanks.

---

**Update $1$**:

Here's what I've done with the case when $n=2$, using the generalised binomial theorem for complex valued index.

$$\begin{aligned}\int\prod_{i=1}^{2}(x-a_i)^{b_i}\mathrm dx&=\int \prod_{i=1}^{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}{b_i\choose k}x^{b_i-k}a_i^{k}\mathrm dx\\ &=\int\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}{b_1\choose k}x^{b_1-k}a_1^k\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{j}{b_2\choose j}x^{b_2-j}a_2^{j}\right)\mathrm dx\end{aligned}$$

Considering the $k$th term of the series with parameters $a_1,b_1$ with the corresponding series with parameters $a_2, b_2$ and integrating term by term.

$$\begin{aligned}\int{b_1\choose k}\frac{(-1)^{k}a_1^k}{x^k}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}{b_2\choose j}\frac{(-1)^{j}a_2^j}{x^{j-(b_1+b_2)}}\mathrm dx&= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{j+k}{b_1\choose k}{b_2\choose j}a_1^ka_2^j\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^{k+j-(b_1+b_2)}}\\&=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{j+k}{b_1\choose k}{b_2\choose j}a_1^ka_2^j\left(\frac{x^{(b_1+b_2)-(j+k)+1}}{(b_1+b_2)-(j+k)+1}\right)\end{aligned}$$

The integral we started with is now simply the summation of this $k$th term with $k$ varying discretely from $k=0$ to $k=\infty$.

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int\prod_{i=1}^{2}(x-a_i)^{b_i}\mathrm dx=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{j+k}{b_1\choose k}{b_2\choose j}a_1^ka_2^j\left(\frac{x^{(b_1+b_2)-(j+k)+1}}{(b_1+b_2)-(j+k)+1}\right)}$$

---

Similarly for the case when $n=3$

$$\begin{aligned}\int\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}{b_1\choose k}x^{b_1-k}a_1^k\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{j}{b_2\choose j}x^{b_2-j}a_2^j\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{i}{b_3\choose i}x^{b_3-i}a_3^i\right)\mathrm dx\end{aligned}$$

Considering the $k$the term of the first sequence and the $j$th term of the second sequence with the third series.

$$\begin{aligned}(-1)^{j+k}{b_1\choose k}{b_2\choose j}a_1^ka_2^j\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{i}{b_3\choose i}a_3^i\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^{i+j+k-(b_1+b_2+b_3)}}\end{aligned}$$

*Now how can this summation be written out as both $j$ and $k$ are varying parameters*? Also is the approach correct, and whether it can be said that the general integral would be the sum with proper summation notation of the following expression $$\left((-1)^{\sum k_i}\prod_{i=1}^{n}{b_i\choose k_i}\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i^{k_i}\right)\left(\frac{x^{\sum {b_i}-\sum k_i}+1}{\sum b_i-\sum {k_i}+1}\right)$$ where $k_i$ represents the value being taken on by the  respective parameters or indexes of summation like the $i,j,k$ in the above cases?

---

**Update $2$**:

I think that the correct way to write this summation, since it is summing over all possible combinations of the indexes $k_i$, is as follows.

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{\sigma}\left((-1)^{\sum k_i}\prod_{i=1}^{n}{b_i\choose k_i}\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i^{k_i}\right)\left(\frac{x^{\sum {b_i}-\sum k_i}+1}{\sum b_i-\sum {k_i}+1}\right), \sigma:=0\le k_i\lt\infty\forall i\in[1,n]\cap\mathbb{Z^{+}}}$$

Is this correct, could someone check my work? Thanks

Comment: For $(1+x)^e$ look for "Newton's binomial theorem".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem

Comment: This is how my question came about. From the binomial theorem, you can write $$\prod_{i=1}^{n} (x - a_i)^{b_i} = \sum_{\kappa \ge 0} \binom{\beta}{\kappa} \, (-1)^{|\kappa|} \, \alpha^\kappa \, x^{|\beta| - |\kappa|}$$ using the multi-indices $\alpha = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$, $\beta = (b_1, \ldots, b_n)$, $\kappa = (k_1, \ldots, k_n)$, and integrate term by term, $$\int \! \prod_{i=1}^{n} (x - a_i)^{b_i} \, dx = \sum_{\kappa \ge 0} \binom{\beta}{\kappa} \, (-1)^{|\kappa|} \, \alpha^\kappa \int \! x^{|\beta| - |\kappa|} \, dx \;.$$ Unfortunately, ...

Comment: ... the result not only depends on the possible combinations of $\beta$ and $\kappa$, e.g. if $|\beta|$ is integer and there is $\kappa$ s.t. $|\kappa| = |\beta|+1$, but also has all these multi-combinations of $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\kappa$ as coefficients. I was wondering if these have been abstracted into some special function, which might even be implemented somewhere.

Comment: @student But aren't all the possible combinations governed by simply varying the indexes $k_i$ since individually under a specific summation with the index denoted by say $k_r$, $b_r,a_r$ are fixed? So the general term is correct, the only problem is caused by the incorrect summation?

Comment: Note that $(x-a)^b$ may only be defined for $x>a.$

Comment: @zhw. Yes. I am aware of that, but that would only imply that the integral exists for $x\ge\text{max}\{a_i\}\forall i\in[1,n]\cap\mathbb{Z^{+}}$, the only cause of ambiguity is the summation over the combinations of the indexes $k_i$.

Comment: I guess that the respective convergence conditions should be satisfied, in particular, conditions allowing to integrate series term by term.

Comment: @AlexRavsky I do not have background in real analysis. I only tried this using elementary integration techniques. I get that there should be some radius of convergence for the series expansion and through some research, I see that it is $1$. So how to use that information? I believe that would only impose restrictions on $a_i$ for which the integral converges. I did not consider this earlier. I only treated the integrand as a traditional polynomial-type function.